# how to resolve a dependency between two tightly coupled namespace(in different assembly)?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, circular-dependency

suppose i have an interface called `ITestService` with it's paired implementation, lets call it `DefaultTestService` in Assembly "A". I register `DefaultTestService` class as `ITestService` service in Autofac container. On the other hand assembly "A" has a reference to assembly "B".now I want to resolve DefaultTestService through it's corresponding interface (ITestService) in assembly "B", for doing this first I have to add reference to assembly "A" so that I can access and pass ITestService to `Resolve<T>()` method.

**circular dependency !**

ok.we can solve it by assigning a key for a component and resolve it by key.but what if the dependency not registered by me (and a key not assigned to it)?

Any idea?
thanks for you'r suggestion.

Comment: Does `ITestService` actually exist in *both* assembly A and B??

Comment: no surely.say it exist!are they two Identical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If assembly A depends on B and both assemblies need `ITestService`, this interface must be defined in assembly B, or a third assembly that both A and B depend on.

Comment: thank for response.in fact you are suggesting me doing some thing correct from the beginning (a good design from software engineering point of view) i will consider it from this point on.but my current problem haven't been solved.+1 vote for you.

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili: I'm sorry. I must have misinterpreted your question. What is the problem you still have?

Comment: @Steven.my problem is that i am not in the beginning of code so that i can decide whether i reference specific assembly in other or not.i have wrote couple of code using this dependency,thus i cant dereference the referenced assembly.