# How to access overall AutoFac container to register a dependency in Orchard?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

the question is pretty straightforward.i want to access overall `AutoFac` container so that i can register my dependency in it.

**remark:**

i am not OK with inheriting from `IDependency` cause in my project it results in a circular referencing (of two assemblies).what i wanna do is register a component with a Key and access it with same Key in other assembly. 
thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

i have found a class called `DefaultOrchardHostContainer` in the core ,but it only exposes `Resolve<>` method but not `Register()`.

Comment: The answer that has been provided is fine, but I'd like to provide some info on your actual circular reference issue. In Orchard, Interface mapping for dependency injection is done on interface name, so you may actually define the same interface name in two modules and they will be considered to be the same. This is used in several places in the core modules.
For other types of circular references, it is also possible to use a Work<T> or a Lazy<T> instead of a T in order to break the circle.

Comment: @Le you are a super man.many many thanks.i can't even imagine about using interface name for interface mapping.these information about dependency injection in orchard were very very useful.i am very lucky with learning this stuff from you.i appreciate your response.well done!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add an Autofac module directly to your Orchard module and Orchard will pick it up.  ex...

```
public class MyModule : Module {
   protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder){
      builder.RegisterType<MyDependency>().As<IMyDependency>().InstancePerDependency();
   }
}
```

Comment: IDependency itself doesn't but referencing between two assembly does.check my previous question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507505/how-to-resolve-a-dependency-between-two-tightly-coupled-namespacein-different-a  for more detail.

Comment: can you please mention what you mean by "Orchard module"?

Comment: i think my solution should be this " you can add an Autofac module directly to your Orchard module and Orchard will pick it up."

Comment: Are you not building an Orchard module?  Orchard modules are how you extend functionality in Orchard.

Comment: I'll edit my answer as I understand you're circular dependency thing now. Bummer you can't move that to another assembly.

Comment: i know what is orchard module.i was talking about autofac module.

Comment: one other question here.in the other side when i want to resolve the registered dependency i should use same approach to access the container? yes?

Comment: Yes, those dependencies can be injected using constructor injection like IDependencies do.  If that's what you mean...