# Orchard Injecting Services Into Automapper Resolvers

Tags: c#, automapper, orchardcms, autofac

I'm wondering if we can currently access a autofac container object that is available during the lifetime of the application. I'm trying to set up Automapper for my entities that are set up outside of the Orchard content types, but I can't create custom type resolvers at the moment because they need access to the autofac container.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
 public class OrchardShellEvents : IOrchardShellEvents
    {
        public void Activated()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.ConstructServicesUsing(type => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(type));
            });
        }

        public void Terminating()
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
```

This will allow me to use the autofac service to inject dependencies into automapper TypeConverters like this:

public class PurchaserInfoConverter : ITypeConverter
{
    private readonly IRepository _stateRepo;
    public PurchaserInfoConverter(IRepository stateRepo)
    {
        _stateRepo = stateRepo;
    }

```
public PurchaserInfoRecord Convert(ResolutionContext context)
{
    var viewModel = context.SourceValue as PurchaserInfoViewModel;

    return new PurchaserInfoRecord
    {
        Address = viewModel.Address,
        City = viewModel.City,
        Company = viewModel.Company,
        Address2 = viewModel.Address2,
        Email = viewModel.Email,
        FirstName = viewModel.FirstName,
        LastName = viewModel.LastName,
        Phone = viewModel.Phone,
        State = viewModel.StateId.HasValue ? _stateRepo.Get(viewModel.StateId.Value) : null,
        Zip = viewModel.Zip,
        Fax = viewModel.Fax,
        Title = viewModel.Title
    };
}
```

}

But unfortunately I have not been able to figure out how I can get access to a container object that lasts the lifetime of the application. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Can you check this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584085/how-to-access-overall-autofac-container-to-register-a-dependency-in-orchard

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work for me, for some reason it can never resolve the type converter :/